# Disk space not freed on ext3/raid1 after deleting

Tags: linux, raid, ext3, disk-space-utilization

I have two 120 GB disks in a software raid1 array (i.e. mirrored), showing as `/dev/md2`. There's an ext3 filesystem on top of this, mounted at `/`.

```
# uname -a
Linux svnserv 2.6.26-2-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Jun 21 04:47:08 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Recently, writes to the disk started failing with "**write error: No space left on device**". `df` showed that there's no more disk space. I removed some unused large files, approx. 5 GB, yet error persists.

`df` shows this:

```
# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2              109G  104G     0 100% /
tmpfs                 471M     0  471M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                   10M  100K   10M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 471M     0  471M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md0               44M  9.8M   32M  24% /boot
```

Note that 104 out of 109 GB is used, yet there's 0 GB available.

I'm not running out of inodes:

```
# df -i
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/md2             7208960   55273 7153687    1% /
```

`mdadm` seems to be happy (both disks are active and in sync):

```
# mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 00.90
  Creation Time : Mon Jul 20 18:53:01 2009
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 115218112 (109.88 GiB 117.98 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 115218112 (109.88 GiB 117.98 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
Preferred Minor : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Thu Jul  8 14:34:08 2010
          State : active
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           UUID : 1bb0fff8:38e78897:34693ac2:f3157c61
         Events : 0.71

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0      22        3        0      active sync   /dev/hdc3
       1      22       67        1      active sync   /dev/hdd3
```

How can I make the unused(?) space available?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the wonders of the SO/SF/SU trilogy: [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/132998/no-free-disk-space) was kind of similar, but the answers didn't solve it. There was this comment however:

> Reserved space for root user.
>   Free space is free space for the
>   unpriviledged user, not total free
>   space. Linux doesn't display negative
>   free space, unlike some other UNIX
>   systems, when you start eating up
>   root's reserved space. – pehrs Apr 16
>   at 8:42

According to [this article](http://www.walkernews.net/2007/02/28/tune2fs-increase-linux-free-disk-space/), default space reserved for root is 5% of disk size.

By issuing `tune2fs -m 0 /dev/md2` , the system now reports free space correctly (this system doesn't need root's reserved space).

The problem was not related to RAID at all.