# How to free up disk space in root directory?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, disk-space-utilization

```
df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G   12K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           391M  1.2M  389M   1% /run
/dev/sda6        19G   17G  597M  97% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G  352K  2.0G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   64K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda4       372G   35G  338G  10% /media/shreya/FED815A3D8155AEB
/dev/sda5       453M   36M  390M   9% /media/shreya/c76b5210-3463-43b2-8b4a-8f5b62fdd868
```

I was trying to upgrade to ubuntu 16.04 from ubuntu 14.04 but it was aborted due to insuffficient disk space. I wish to free disk space in / which has used 97% as per the disk space usage above. I have tried sudo apt-get clean and sudo apt-get autoremove, but nothing has helped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No free disk space](https://serverfault.com/questions/132998/no-free-disk-space)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at `/boot`. Ubuntu has the tendency to clog this directory with old kernels. If there are some, you can look what can be cleaned up with

```bash
sudo dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | \
  cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | xargs sudo apt-get --dry-run remove
```

If you are satisfied with the result you can delete them with this command:

```bash
sudo dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | \
  cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

This will also remove all kernel related files in other directories (for the spcific versions). On machines that are running for a longer time this usually frees up some gigabytes for me.

Apart from that ... `/tmp` is always a good place to clean up. `du -hs /*` will show which directory uses how much space. To get a good overview I prefer the non-standard tool `durep`.

Comment: Thanks with these commands i was able to remove files in /boot and get this disk usage to 92%. I did du -hs /* and /bin and /etc have taken a lot of space after /boot. What files can be deleted from both bin and etc?
9.6M /bin
37M /boot
4.0K /cdrom
12K /dev
15M /etc

Comment: Again The upgrade was aborted ..The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 2,580 M free 
space on disk '/'. Please free at least an additional 1,095 M of disk 
space on '/'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages of 
former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'. 
 What else can be deleted, I have deleted log files in /var/log as well..

Answer (score 5):

Try to use this command to get top 20 largest files:

```
du -max / | sort -rn | head -20
```

To remove obsoleted packages (as well as old kernels):

```
apt-get autoremove
```

Check those directories:

```
/var/tmp
/tmp
/var/spool/mail
/var/log
```

Check home directories, remove unused files.